# tikz matrix border width 0 behavior wired

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

Below example set the line width to 0 but it still generate a tiny border around cells.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\d{0pt}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={minimum size=0.5cm, draw, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0,line width=\d},
             nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\d, row sep=-\d,
              ]
{
   1  & 2 & 3  \\
    4 & 5 & 6  \\
    7 & 8 & 9  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

1. The border should be nothing if line width is 0.
2. The output looks like not a square but a rectangle,height a bit more longer than width.

Comment: don't use `draw` if you don't want borders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can check if `\d` is 0 and do not pass the draw option if it is.
   Note the curley braces around the if statement to hide the equals sign from the algorithm splitting up keys and values.

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz, margin=2pt]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \def\d{0pt}
   \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={minimum size=0.5cm, {\ifdim\d=0pt \else draw\fi}, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0,line width=\d},
                nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\d, row sep=-\d,
               ]
   {
       1 & 2 & 3  \\
       4 & 5 & 6  \\
       7 & 8 & 9  \\
   };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   To improve readability you can perform the if statement beforehand and define a command accordingly:

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz, margin=2pt]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \def\d{0pt}
   \ifdim\d=0pt 
       \def\DrawFlag{}%
   \else
       \def\DrawFlag{draw}%
   \fi
   \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={minimum size=0.5cm, \DrawFlag, outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0,line width=\d},
                nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\d, row sep=-\d,
               ]
   {
       1 & 2 & 3  \\
       4 & 5 & 6  \\
       7 & 8 & 9  \\
   };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Maybe your screen is distorting them a little or it's an optical illusion. They are squares. I have measured them and they are 360 pixels high and 360 pixels wide in the screenshot you have provided.

Answer (score 3):

`percuse` already gave you the solution, don't `draw` the borders:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\d{0pt}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={minimum size=0.5cm, 
                    draw=none, %<-------------
                    outer sep=0pt,
                    inner sep=0,
                    line width=\d},
             nodes in empty cells,column sep=-\d, row sep=-\d,
              ]
{
   1  & 2 & 3  \\
    4 & 5 & 6  \\
    7 & 8 & 9  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]